# Read JVM Properties in Maven's pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, build, jvm, pom.xml

I am having a requirement where I am passing a property+value with -D option. I would like to access the value in pom.xml file. Could you please help me to know how can I achieve the same?

For example:
-Dname="BlaBla"

now in pom.xml file how I can get the value of "name"?
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The handling of properties in maven is described here: [POM Reference -> Properties](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)

In your case just use: `${name}`

**Example:**

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>property-test</groupId>
  <artifactId>property-test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <echo>Value of FooBar is: ${FooBar}</echo>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

*Call:*

```
mvn validate -DFooBar="Hello World"
```

*Result:*

```
 [echo] Value of FooBar is: Hello World
```